# Mapbox - Show point of interest markers regardless of zoom level

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-studio

I'm filtering on the `'poi-label'` layer on the default Mapbox Streets V8 data source. What I'd like to have is that certain maki or class labels like `'fitness-centere'` to always be visible (both icon and label) regardless of the zoom level.

I see no clear documentation on how to do this using Mapbox studio. Can it be done in that tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally not possible to have layers in vector tile sources display at "all zoom levels" because they don't exist at all zoom levels within the vector tile sources.

Generally, the Mapbox tilesets are heavily optimised and only include data at the zoom levels that they are intended to display at in the corresponding Mapbox styles.